# Crosstab Query on multiple data points

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that tracks employee quality assessment data. It includes the employee name, 5 yes/no fields tracking important items and the date the user did each task as column headings. Each employee gets 10 records a month so it includes a lot of data about how well our employees are doing at those 5 tasks.

I would like a report that shows me the monthly averages of these 5 yes/no fields: Appeal, NRP, Churn, Protocol, and Resub. I want those to be the Row Headers. I want the column headers to be sequential Months and the Averages to be the values. I can do this with a crosstab query for a single item such as avg:Appeal as the value and the user as the row header. How can I construct my query to use all 5 yes/no fields? They hoped for result would look like:

[Table image showing how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvReB.jpg)

Comments on the Correct Answer:
June7 came up with a great answer! I changed the True to False in the DataUNION query because I wanted the Accuracy percentage and the true indicates an error on the employee evaluation. I also added in a few fields I didn't mention before. Thank you very much for helping a scrub out June7! Reading through what you wrote inspired me to start taking an SQL course on Lynda. I know its basic but you have to start somewhere and I'm getting to the point where access's builtin functions aren't doing it for me. Hopefully with the next question I'll be able to address the concerns of the commentators below that were upset that I didn't have code for myself that I had tried first. 
[June7's revised Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BTAD.jpg)

Comment: The answer can only be *yes, it is possible*. You need to ask a question that is answerable. See [ask] and create an [mcve]. Without a input data, your current attempt and expected output all we can do is guess.

Comment: read this [mso post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) about what a good question for sql queries should look like and then [edit] your question. It also has some helpful links to other guidance, like http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/. Use it, apply it. You can't fix your question with a comment.

Comment: If the yes/no fields are columns in your data, you will need to normalize the data to get each question on a separate record if you want them to be rows on the final crosstab.  As noted above, though - this is just an educated guess without a better question with tables layouts and other important details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Don George! You are correct in that the table includes (among other things) the 5 Fields I listed and the date as columns. What I think you're saying is create another table turning each Yes/No into a separate record?  What I am thinking is the 3 column headings as: Nate Date, A lookup for the 5 fields, and the Value of yes/no? Then I can Crosstab so the Row Heading is the lookup, the The collumn Heading the Date, and the value is the average of the yes/no.

Comment: Again: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description. Use [this](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to provide readable data.

Comment: Example shows percentage, not average. Percentage of what?

Comment: Its the percentage of yes's to the total number of records. So if they had 45 yes tics on 50 total records,  it would show 90%.

Comment: Clarify - each record can have only one checked field? Really should modify data structure.

Comment: So each employee has a randomly selected 10 accounts reviewed each month. They are evaluated on the the trends I listed which are yes/no fields. Yes's are bad. (That's why having 4 appeals in June is actually a good thing) Thus the table could be created as CREATE TABLE Data (emp TEXT, TaskDate INTEGER, Appeal Yes/No, NRP Yes/No, Churn Yes/No, Protocol Yes/No, Resub Yes,No) What I am trying to get is the total accuracy percentage for all rows/records.

Comment: Here is another good source of info about SQL and other languages: https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Rene and any others (Don George?), would possible consider removing the negative review on the OP? I hope that I have corrected the question to address your concerns. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

Query1: DataUNION

```
SELECT ID AS SourceID, Emp, Year([TaskDate]) AS Yr, Format([TaskDate], "mmm") AS Mo, "Appeal" AS Trend 
      FROM Data 
      WHERE Appeal=True
UNION SELECT ID, Emp, Year([TaskDate]), Format([TaskDate], "mmm"), "NRP" 
      FROM Data WHERE NRP = True
UNION SELECT ID, Emp, Year([TaskDate]), Format([TaskDate], "mmm"), "Churn" 
      FROM Data WHERE Churn = True
UNION SELECT ID, Emp, Year([TaskDate]), Format([TaskDate], "mmm"), "Protocol" 
      FROM Data WHERE Protocol = True
UNION SELECT ID, Emp, Year([TaskDate]), Format([TaskDate], "mmm"), "Resub" 
      FROM Data WHERE Resub = True;
```

Query2: DataCOUNT

```
SELECT DataUNION.Yr, DataUNION.Mo, DataUNION.Trend, 
Count(DataUNION.Emp) AS CountOfEmp, Q.CntYrMo, Count([Emp])/[CntYrMo]*100 AS Pct
FROM (SELECT Year([TaskDate]) AS Yr, Format([TaskDate],"mmm") AS Mo, Count(Data.ID) AS CntYrMo
      FROM Data
      GROUP BY Year([TaskDate]), Format([TaskDate],"mmm")) AS Q 
INNER JOIN DataUNION ON (Q.Yr = DataUNION.Yr) AND (Q.Mo = DataUNION.Mo)
GROUP BY DataUNION.Yr, DataUNION.Mo, DataUNION.Trend, Q.CntYrMo;
```

Query3:

```
TRANSFORM First(DataCount.Pct) AS FirstOfPct
SELECT DataCount.Yr, DataCount.Trend
FROM DataCount
GROUP BY DataCount.Yr, DataCount.Trend
PIVOT DataCount.Mo In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
```

Comment: June7, this is great! Thank you very much for the code. I don't know a lot about SQL so you really helped me out. I'm attaching a screenshot of your code above. Could you make a suggestion on the best way to turn the count into a percentage of the total records? For example: In June there were 4 appeal checks on a total of 1236 records.

Comment: Percentage by year/month? There were 1236 records in June? Only 4 were Appeal?

Comment: Correct. These are actually medical records so less than 98% accuracy is considered unacceptable.

Comment: See if you like the revised queries.

Comment: That worked great! I updated my question above so I could link the image and marked you as the answer. Thank you again!