# Selection that repeats a group of columns based on a separate column having a different value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello and thanks for having a look!

I'm trying to make a complex selection from a prior query and I'm having a hard time locating a solution, in part because I'm having a hard time describing what I'm after or what to search for.  Here's the rub:

What I have ([table1]):

| identifier | month | item 1 | item 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz-1 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| xyz-2 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| xyz-1 | 11 | 1 | 1 |
| xyz-2 | 11 | 1 | 1 |

What I would like if possible:

| identifier | item 1 - 10 | item 2 - 10 | item 1 - 11 | item 2 - 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz-1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| xyz-2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

With the goal being that I have a set of Items for every month in the year (above example showing only Oct and Nov).  I feel like a Group By and Join solution is what I need, but I'm stuck after spending all day on this.

Any help is appreciated!

**Update 1 - Close Solution:**

Using a combination of suggestions from two contributors below, I was able to rewrite my original query that generated my starting table above.

I had been running this query:

```
TRANSFORM First([Points]) AS ItemPoints
SELECT identifier, month
FROM [source]
GROUP identifier, month
PIVOT name;
```

But this created a column for month which is pretty obvious in hindsight.

The solution was the following query:

```
TRANSFORM First([source].Points) AS ItemPoints
SELECT [source].identifier
FROM [itemNames], [source]
GROUP BY [source].identifier
ORDER BY ScoreMonth & [itemNames].ItemId
PIVOT ScoreMonth & [itemNames].ItemId;
```

Where [itemNames] is a query that returns a list of unique item names, the "item 1", "item 2" bit.

This resulted in the following table:

| identifier | 10item 1 | 10item 2 | 11item 1 | 11item 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz-1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| xyz-2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Which I can work with :)

**Update 2 - Wasn't Solved**

Soon after I posted that the solution was found, I realized that the values were incorrect because of the aggregate function on the Transform line.  I'm looking into this again, and the solution presented below with the DlookUp() function.

**Update 3 - Solution**

I found that the problem with my Transform query was that the ORDER BY and PIVOT lines needed to reference the [source] table and not the [itemNames] table.  I also changed the First() function to Min(), but either work :)

```
TRANSFORM Min([source].Points) AS ItemPoints
SELECT [source].identifier
FROM [source]
GROUP BY [source].identifier
ORDER BY ScoreMonth & '_' & [source].ItemId
PIVOT ScoreMonth & '_' & [source].ItemId;
```

Comment: firstly, columns should be unique

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548072/crosstab-query-on-multiple-data-points

Comment: Sorry, non-unique headers in my post was an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

What your are trying to do is called a cross-tab query.  However your query has 2 column headings Month and Item.  Month is invisible.  Access and Excel only allow 1 column heading in a cross-tab query.  So my solution is to manually generate the 2 column cross-tab.
So for the manual cross-tab we need to do a cross-join query to generate all the rows and columns we will need. Then we use a calculated-field and the dlookup function to insert the correct value from Table1 into the correct cell in the upcoming cross-tab querie's root query.
[image]
ItemNames is a table of all the item names, Months (here 2 months), Identifiers is all identifiers.  Since we cant have 2 columns with the same name we are going to use ItemMonth as a work around.

```
Value: Nz(DLookUp("item1","Table1","identifier = '" & [identifier] & "'   AND monthnumber = " & [MonthNumber]),0)

ItemMonth: [MonthNumber] & [ItemName]

'Table 1

ID  identifier  monthnumber item1   item2
3   xyz-1   10  0   0
4   xyz-2   10  0   0
5   xyz-1   11  1   1
6   xyz-2   11  1   1

'after cross join : query1 in picture

MonthNumber ItemName    identifier  Value   ItemMonth
10  Item 1  xyz-1   0   10Item 1
11  Item 1  xyz-1   1   11Item 1
10  Item 2  xyz-1   0   10Item 2
11  Item 2  xyz-1   1   11Item 2
10  Item 1  xyz-2   0   10Item 1
11  Item 1  xyz-2   1   11Item 1
10  Item 2  xyz-2   0   10Item 2
11  Item 2  xyz-2   1   11Item 2
```

The cross-tab set up is as simple as it gets.  The cross-tab is a type of totals query so pay attention to the summary functions:

[image]

```
'result of our cross-tab query but the column names are still wrong so we will fix that with a report

identifier  10Item 1    10Item 2    11Item 1    11Item 2
xyz-1   0   0   1   1
xyz-2   0   0   1   1
```

To generate the repot I just selected the cross-tab query and hit report.  Then went into design mode and edited all the column labels.  If you have to do this whole process frequently or have a whole lot of items use VBA to auto adjust the report labels.

[image]

Aside 1.  In Access, cross-tab queries bug-out if they are based on even slightly complicated queries.  If your cross-tab is based on a query and it doesn't work try turning the cross-tab's query into a table with a make-table query.  Then base the cross-tab on the new table.

Aside 2.  I suggest Looking at the cross-tab as only a way to view your data.  Every time you add or subtract an item to this data that results in adding or subtracting 12 columns to the cross-tab.  that means you have to adjust any reports and forms based on a cross-tab every time the items change.  Way to much work.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, good sir!  I will study this today and let you know of my results!

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you've laid out here and I'm going to try and implement now.  This query is part of a dynamic reporting system I'm building in VBA, so the renaming of the column headers and the adding/removing of things should be no problem, thank you for pointing out nonetheless.

Comment: Okay, you did help a great deal, but once I got into trying your suggested solution I found got confused by the DLookUp parameter "item1".  While working on this I learned more about CrossTab queries, though, and as a result was able to rewrite the query that generated the table in my post (I referred to it as a "prior query")  :)