# How to count number of fields in a single record that contain xyz

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large table with A LOT of fields.   Each record has fields, each with a unique name, that contain one of three values.  Confirmed, Unconfirmed, Issue.
It's basically structured like this:

| DocumentID | datapoint1 | datapoint2 | datapoint3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Document 1 | Confirmed | Unconfirmed | Confirmed |
| Document 2 | Issue | Confirmed | Confirmed |

Etc...

I need to count the number of each occurrence per document. IE..

Document 1 = 2 confirmed, 1 unconfirmed

Document 2 = 1 Issue, 2 confirmed

Etc..

And be able to display these values on forms and reports.

Part of the problem is there are 67 fields that I need to do this for.  This is super easy in excel but apparently not so easy in access.  In excel I would just do a countif formula at the end of the row.  But access doesn't do that.

Counting vertically seems to be no problem in access.  But I haven't found a way to count horizontally across a single record. Maybe I'm just going about this all wrong?

Comment: Your database table looks denormalized - is it possible for you to correct issues with your database design at all?

Comment: in short create a query based on the original table.  the only thing the query has to do is add a calculated field.  set the value of the calculated field to that that countif formula.  later create a secondquery that just returns a sum of any calculated fields you made in the first query.  use these queries as the control source of the controls you use to display the sums in any forms and reports.

Comment: Exactly what is "a lot of fields"? If much more that the 3 shown in example, options are 1) VBA or 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548072/crosstab-query-on-multiple-data-points

Comment: I just noticed post specifies 67 fields are involved which means a UNION query is out as it is limited to 50 SELECT lines. That leaves VBA custom function or restructuring schema. This is a fairly common topic in numerous forums.

Comment: @mazoula, COUNTIF not supported in Access - it is Excel function. With only 3 fields, it is fairly simple with IIf(): `IIf(datapoint1="Confirmed",1,0) + IIf(datapoint2="Confirmed",1,0) + IIf(datapoint3="Confirmed",1,0)`. Do similar field calcs for other two values. However, 67 fields makes this unfeasible and VBA custom function is called for. It would open a recordset of 1 record and loop fields and execute IIf() test to determine if variable should be incremented. Basically building your own "CountIf" function.

Comment: my bad, I was trying to use the posters terminology.  I should have been more clear.

Comment: Consider the amount of time required to create a workaround in VBA versus restructuring your tables to 3rd normal form. Future workarounds would probably be necessary if you chhose the former.

Comment: I think the overall structure of the database is the issue at hand. As others have indicated.    I'm trying to get my head around the different levels of normalization and how they apply to my project.  I would rather not need multiple workarounds every time I need to get a new calculation.  So I've scrapped the database and instead focusing on the correct way to structure it first.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1: Create a normalized table from original data and run a crosstab query over it**

Create Normalized Table (Documents_Normal):

```
DIM dbs AS DATABASE : SET dbs= currentdb
DIM td AS NEW TABLEDEF
SET td= dbs.createtabledef("Documents_Normal")
WITH td
    .fields.append .createfield("DocumentID" , dbtext , 20)
    .fields.append .createfield("datapoint"  , dbtext , 20)
    .fields.append .createfield("Status"     , dbtext , 20)
END WITH
dbs.tabledefs.append td
SET td= NOTHING
SET dbs=NOTHING
```

Populate Documents_Normal From Documents:

```
CONST Datapoints_Count= 67
DIM dbs AS DATABASE
SET dbs= currentdb
DIM rs1 , rs2 AS RECORDSET
SET rs1= dbs.openrecordset("Documents")
SET rs2= dbs.openrecordset("Documents_Normal")
DIM i AS INTEGER

DO WHILE NOT rs1.EOF
    FOR i = 1 TO Datapoints_Count
        rs2.addnew
        rs2("DocumentID")= rs1("DocumentID")
        rs2("datapoint") = "datapoint" + TRIM(i)
        rs2("Status")    = rs1("datapoint" + TRIM(i))
        rs2.update
    NEXT
    rs1.movenext
LOOP

rs1.close : SET rs1= NOTHING
rs2.close : SET rs2= NOTHING
SET dbs= NOTHING
```

The crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM COUNT(datapoint)
SELECT DocumentID
FROM Documents_Normal
GROUP BY DocumentID
PIVOT Status
```

**Solution 2 : Direct count from original data**

Add 3 fields to the Documents table to hold counts:

```
docmd.runsql "ALTER TABLE Documents ADD COLUMN Count_Issue       LONG"
docmd.runsql "ALTER TABLE Documents ADD COLUMN Count_Unconfirmed LONG"
docmd.runsql "ALTER TABLE Documents ADD COLUMN Count_Confirmed   LONG"
```

Count each status in each record:

```
CONST Datapoints_Count= 67
DIM dbs AS DATABASE : SET dbs= currentdb
DIM rs AS RECORDSET
SET rs= dbs.openrecordset("Documents")

DIM status AS STRING
DIM N_Issue , N_Confirmed , N_Unconfirmed AS LONG
DO WHILE NOT rs.eof
    N_Issue= 0
    N_Confirmed= 0
    N_Unconfirmed= 0
    FOR i = 1 TO Datapoints_Count
        status= rs("datapoint" & Trim(i))
        SELECT CASE status
            CASE "Issue"
                N_Issue= N_Issue + 1
            CASE "Confirmed"
                N_Confirmed= N_Confirmed + 1
            CASE Else  
                N_Unconfirmed= N_Unconfirmed + 1
        END SELECT
    NEXT
    rs.edit
    rs("Count_Issue")       = N_Issue
    rs("Count_Confirmed")   = N_Confirmed
    rs("Count_Unconfirmed") = N_Unconfirmed
    rs.update
    rs.movenext
LOOP

rs.close : SET rs= NOTHING
SET dbs= NOTHING
```